# Debezium SQL Server connector emits unknown record moment after completing setup with snapshot.mode:schema_only

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am setting up a Debezium SQL Server connector. When `snapshot.mode` is `schema_only`, Debezium sends one record the moment after streaming has started, even though the are no new entries in the event log. The record causes an error on `ExtractField$Key` transform, since the unknown record does not contain the desired field in key. I have been able to work around this issue by removing the transform for the initial run and then adding it back up. I have not managed to check the contents of that record, since it never reaches the topic, even without the transform. The key is extracted from the "real" records just fine.

A few questions:

1. What is that record and why is it sent?
2. How is it filtered out not to reach the topic, with the transform removed?
3. Is there a way to log Debezium records?

Log:

```
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,292] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] No previous offset has been found (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:68)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,292] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] According to the connector configuration only schema will be snapshotted (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:73)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,292] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 1 - Preparing (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:90)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,499] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 2 - Determining captured tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:99)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,591] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Adding table PCH.dbo.DATABASECHANGELOG to the list of capture schema tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:192)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,592] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Adding table PCH.dbo.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK to the list of capture schema tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:192)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,592] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Adding table PCH.dbo.event_log to the list of capture schema tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:192)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,592] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 3 - Locking captured tables [PCH.dbo.event_log] (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:106)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,592] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Setting locking timeout to 10 s (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:126)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,596] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Executing schema locking (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:131)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,596] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Locking table PCH.dbo.event_log (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:138)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,598] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 4 - Determining snapshot offset (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:112)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,600] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 5 - Reading structure of captured tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:115)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,693] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Reading structure of schema 'PCH' (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:199)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,796] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 6 - Persisting schema history (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:119)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,796] WARN [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] The Kafka Connect schema name 'oi-pc-cdc-payment-case-handling-inquiry-events-1.dbo.event_log.Value' is not a valid Avro schema name, so replacing with 'oi_pc_cdc_payment_case_handling_inquiry_events_1.dbo.event_log.Value' (io.debezium.util.SchemaNameAdjuster:172)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,796] WARN [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] The Kafka Connect schema name 'oi-pc-cdc-payment-case-handling-inquiry-events-1.dbo.event_log.Key' is not a valid Avro schema name, so replacing with 'oi_pc_cdc_payment_case_handling_inquiry_events_1.dbo.event_log.Key' (io.debezium.util.SchemaNameAdjuster:172)
[2022-11-16 08:41:16,797] WARN [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] The Kafka Connect schema name 'oi-pc-cdc-payment-case-handling-inquiry-events-1.dbo.event_log.Envelope' is not a valid Avro schema name, so replacing with 'oi_pc_cdc_payment_case_handling_inquiry_events_1.dbo.event_log.Envelope' (io.debezium.util.SchemaNameAdjuster:172)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,098] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Schema locks released. (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:158)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,098] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot step 7 - Skipping snapshotting of data (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:135)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,100] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot - Final stage (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource:88)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,101] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Removing locking timeout (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSnapshotChangeEventSource:239)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,103] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Snapshot ended with SnapshotResult [status=COMPLETED, offset=SqlServerOffsetContext [sourceInfoSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source:STRUCT}, sourceInfo=SourceInfo [serverName=oi-pc-cdc-payment-case-handling-inquiry-events-1, changeLsn=NULL, commitLsn=000002a6:00005ba0:0001, eventSerialNo=null, snapshot=FALSE, sourceTime=2022-11-16T08:41:16.796Z], snapshotCompleted=true, eventSerialNo=1]] (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:156)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,103] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Connected metrics set to 'true' (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:236)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,103] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Starting streaming (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerChangeEventSourceCoordinator:87)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,103] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Last position recorded in offsets is 000002a6:00005ba0:0001(NULL)[1] (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource:139)
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,202] ERROR [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=inquiry_events_testing_8-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:195)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:223)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:149)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:355)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:258)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown field: payment_id
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField.apply(ExtractField.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:207)
    ... 11 more
[2022-11-16 08:41:17,203] INFO [inquiry_events_testing_8|task-0] Stopping down connector (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:243)
```

Connector configuration:

```
  {
    "name": "inquiry_events_testing_8",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
      "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
      "database.hostname": "${db_cluster}",
      "database.dbname" : "PCH",
      "database.user": "${db_user}",
      "database.password": "${db_password}",
      "table.include.list": "dbo.event_log",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka.core.svc:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic": "oi-pc-cdc-payment-case-handling-inquiry-events-db-history",
      "database.server.name": "${db_server_name}",
      "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
      "message.key.columns": "dbo.event_log:payment_id",
      "transforms": "Reroute, Unwrap, ExtractValueFrom",
      "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
      "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "${db_server_name}.dbo.event_log",
      "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "${sink_topic}",
      "transforms.Unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
      "transforms.ExtractValueFrom.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField\$Key",
      "transforms.ExtractValueFrom.field": "payment_id"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is `payment_tnt_id` a column in the `dbo.case_event_log` table? It's meant to be a key column so that it provides a unique message id.

Comment: Yes, ```payment_tnt_id``` is a column in ```dbo.case_event_log``` table. I have not found that ```payment_tnt_id``` has to be unique though. Could you link the place in documentation that says that message id has to be unique?

Comment: _There is no limit to the number of columns that you use to create custom message keys. However, it’s best to use the minimum number that are required to specify a unique key._ [Ref](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-message-key-columns)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Hm, I don't really see the point of having a unique key for each record, since I want the messages in kafka topic to be partitioned in a certain way. 

[For two records with the same key, the producer will always choose the same partition.](https://codingharbour.com/apache-kafka/the-introduction-to-kafka-topics-and-partitions/)